# Converting text document coordinates 'x, y' to float point list object

Tags: python, kivy

I have a text file containing coordinates I want to put into a python-based graph (graph is from kivy.garden.graph module, which I have working).

The text file, when I use open().read(), looks like this:

```
(0, 1.836957)
(1, 1.836995)
(2, 1.837073)
(3, 1.837111)
(4, 1.837111)
```

And is string type. And I need it to go into the graph module as:

```
[(0, 1.836957), (1, 1.836995), (2, 1.837073), (3, 1.837111), (4, 1.837111)]
```

Note, the text file will be updated in real-time, which the graph module can handle. Or at best, pick the last 10 x,y points created. Also, I can manipulate the text file as I have output it myself from another function outside.

Apologies for the simplicity of this, but I have been scratching my head over converting this now for the last 24 hours. I have only managed to get this:

**(space after the comma at the end)**

```
[(0, 1.836957), (1, 1.836995), (2, 1.837073), (3, 1.837111), (4, 1.837111), ]
```

Note the extra comma and space, and it's only through string manipulation using replace(), rather than what I need is float type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `strip` and `split` methods to break each line into the appropriate coordinates.

```
with open("myfile.txt") as fh:
    coords = []
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip('()\n')  # Get rid of the newline and  parentheses
        line = line.split(', ')  # Split into two parts
        c = tuple(float(x) for x in line)  # Make the tuple
        coords.append(c)
```

The whole thing can be done more efficiently with a list comprehension; the above is more readable.

```
with open("myfile.txt") as fh:
    coords = [tuple(float(x) for x in line.strip('()\n').split(', ')) for line in fh]
```

Comment: The first solution worked a treat, the second however had apostrophes around each coordinate. I'm very, VERY happy though, thank you so much chepner!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to map `float` to each of the values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input provided and the output you are trying to achieve, you can make use of [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast).

Furthermore, for this particular case, it might make it easier to manage the data if you use [readlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) instead of `read()`. `readlines` will give you a list.

Take a look at this:

```
import ast
x = list(ast.literal_eval(','.join(i.strip() for i in open('some_file').readlines())))
```

Input:

```
(0, 1.836957)
(1, 1.836995)
(2, 1.837073)
(3, 1.837111)
(4, 1.837111)
```

Output: (type will be a list)

```
[(0, 1.836957), (1, 1.836995), (2, 1.837073), (3, 1.837111), (4, 1.837111)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it will be easier if the data were saved just as:
number1 \t number2 \n
Anyway, one option to do what you want will be:

```
import json # This library has lost os ways to load and save data
f=open('file.txt','r')
# Remove the \n at the end of each line and replace () for []
# Create the data with all the tuples.
# json only reads list, thats why we have to transforn it into a tuple at the end
data=[tuple(json.loads(l[:-1].replace('(','[').replace(')',']'))) for l in f]
f.close()
```

This should work. If the file if updated i think you should open it again at it will work